# How do I uncheck/check all my checkboxes at once?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have a screen with about 500 checkboxes on it. The first checkbox has to be able to uncheck/check all the others, which my current code does.

I'd like to know if I can make it any faster/instant. Because I'm currently using a For loop it takes a while before it is done.

This is my code:

```
Dim xCheckBox As CheckBox
For Each xCheckBox In Application.ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If xCheckBox.Name <> Application.ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("ToggleCheck").Name Then
        xCheckBox.Value = Application.ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("ToggleCheck").Value
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just set them all at once:

```
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("ToggleCheck").Value
```